# Only Guest Account on new Ubuntu laptop!

Tags: users

On start, the new laptop has only a **Guest Account**. **No Standard User account or Administrator account** is visible.

Hence I cannot use the laptop or even change any settings.

On the first start, I could set the WiFi password and it accessed the Net. Then, when trying to change the City, on typing the first letter, something happened and the result is above. On a second restart, identical results were obtained, except that the WiFi was already accepted.

Since then, all starts show only the Guest account.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu into your computer or are you using a live CD (or live USB)?

Comment: By *guest account* do you mean a user named guest? Did you try using `sudo` with either empty password or something trivial like `ubuntu`? I shall say, in the worst case you can set a password through a root-shell of grub *(you aren't probably see it by default, but you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to see)*, and change a user name.